# How to Name an nested array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

My tool  Pa11y gives me output in below JSON format

```
var result=[{name:'A'},{name:'B;}]
```

I want it to refer it as below so that it can be stored in mongoDB

```
var result={person:[{name:'A'},{name:'B;} ]}
```

Please help

Comment: `var newRes = {person : result}`

Comment: Are you aware that what you provided is not valid JSON? Your problem *could* be related to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use your `result` as the value to a key in an object. The key can be named arbitrarily as you need it:

```
var result=[{name:'A'},{name:'B;}]

var person = {
    person: result
}
```